# php MS Access SQL Query with multiple string parameters

Tags: php

I am trying to construct an SQL statement with two string parameters. Essentially I am querying a MS Access table with php.

Is my syntax correct below?

```
$parm1 = "TPMS";
$parm2 = "Clamp In";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like ".$parm1 ."and where productderivative like". $parm2;
```

Now I have tried a one parameter string called $parm1, The syntax of the string is as below. Please note this is a MS Access table I am querying with php.

```
$parm1 = "'TPMS'";
```

Now the corresponding MS Access SQL statement is as follows which works:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like $parm1 order by fullname asc"
```

Now the corresponding MS Access SQL statement with two parameters which does not work. Can somebody tell me why the second parameter does not work in the SQL statement? Is it perhaps my syntax?

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like $parm1 and "
$sql .= "where productderivative like $parm2 order by fullname asc";
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to enclose your string literals with single quotes: `'`

```php
$parm1 = "'TPMS'";
$parm2 = "'Clamp In'"; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like ".$parm1 ."and where productderivative like". $parm2;
```

Secondly, a `LIKE` statement is useful with a wildcard character

1. **`%`** The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters
2. **`?`** The question mark(for Access) represents a single character

So that if you are looking for occurences that may include `TPMS` anywhere after the , you would have

For example:

```
$parm1 = "'TPMS%'";
$parm1 = "'%TPMS'";
$parm1 = "'%TPMS%'";
$parm1 = "'?T%'";
$parm1 = "'T?%?%'";
$parm1 = "'T%o'";
```

Which evaluate to the following SQL:

```sql
    WHERE productfamily LIKE 'TPMS%'    --Finds any values that starts with "TPMS"
    WHERE productfamily LIKE '%TPMS'    --Finds any values that ends with "TPMS"
    WHERE productfamily LIKE '%TPMS%'   --Finds any values that have "TPMS" in any position
    WHERE productfamily LIKE '?T%'  --Finds any values that have "T" in the second position
    WHERE productfamily LIKE 'T?%?%'    --Finds any values that starts with "T" and are at least 3 characters in length
    WHERE productfamily LIKE 'T%o'  --Finds any values that starts with "T" and ends with "o"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll adapt the code from the documentation here https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/ to your situation.

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "yourpathhere\archive.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$parm1 = 'TPMS';
$parm2 = 'Clamp In';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM archive where productfamily like :family and where productderivative like :derivative';

$pdo->prepare($sql)
$pdo->bindParam(':family', $parm1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->bindParam(':derivative', $parm2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo->execute();
```

That should get you there.  This is untested.  If anything fails, let me know and I'll create some tables and run it.

Comment: Hi Pendo It's a MS Access Database not MYSQL I am using